What is this tool with springs on a shaft?

Does anyone know what this is? I got it in a box of tools.

Suspension rods for a clothes washing machine.
Stolen from the Internet: Suspension rods form part of your washer's suspension. They keep the cabinet stable and secure during the washing and spinning cycles. These rods are normally attached to the suspension springs.
If it helps, I think this is the exact suspension rods shown in the image.

I've never heard of such a thing.  Could you expand on how they are used in a washing machine?   Are they for front loaders or top loaders?   What is their purpose ?

I've seen similar arrangements on Front Loading washing machines. These machines have a tub within a tub arrangement where the external tub and drive motor assembly are suspended from springs and the internal tub is connected to the drive motor through an axle . The pictured mechanism dampens the external tub motion during a spin cycle.

@DelphicOracle Yeah , when I looked up the washer models in the Amazon product, two were top loaders and one was a front loader.
